# picocli: show help if no parameter given

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

I would like to show the help automatically when I run my  CLI app without parameters.
I have seen that this question appears multiply times on StackOverflow. I spent significant time figuring this out, I have read the [official document](https://picocli.info/), checked articles, but still not clear how to achieve this.

This is what I have:

**Main class**

```
@Command(
        subcommands = {C1.class, C2.class}
)
public class HelloCli implements Callable<Integer>  {

    @Option(names = {"?", "-h", "--help"},
            usageHelp = true,
            description = "display this help message")
    boolean usageHelpRequested;

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("wanna show the help here");
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(new HelloCli()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

**The class that handles the *show-user* function:**

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "show-user",
                     aliases = "-show-user")
public class C1 implements Callable<Integer> {

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"?", "-h", "--help"},
                        usageHelp = true,
                        description = "display this help message")
    boolean usageHelpRequested;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-p1"},
                        description = "show-user: param 1")
    String  p1;

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("executing the 'show-user' business logic...");
        System.out.println("param 1: " + p1);
        return 4;
    }
}
```

**The class to handle the *create-user* command:**

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "create-user",
                     aliases = "-create-user")
public class C2  implements Callable<Integer> {

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"?", "-h", "--help"},
                        usageHelp = true,
                        description = "display this help message")
    boolean usageHelpRequested;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-p1"},
                        description = "create-user: another param 1")
    String  p1;

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("executing the 'create-user' business logic...");
        System.out.println("param 1: " + p1);
        return 5;
    }
}
```

**Case 1: when I call this app with `-h` then the help is displayed properly:**

```
Usage: <main class> [?] [COMMAND]
      ?, -h, --help   display this help message
Commands:
  show-user, -show-user
  create-user, -create-user
```

**Case 2: showing help for the 1st function, calling `show-user -h`:**

```
Usage: <main class> show-user [?] [-p1=<p1>]
      ?, -h, --help   display this help message
      -p1=<p1>        show-user: param 1
```

**Case 3: chowing help for the 1st function, calling `create-user -h`:**

```
Usage: <main class> create-user [?] [-p1=<p1>]
      ?, -h, --help   display this help message
      -p1=<p1>        create-user: another param 1
```

**Case 4: calling my app without param shows this:**

```
wanna show the help here
```

**My question is simple:**

How to show the help when I run my CLI tool without params (`Case 4`)?

I guess that I need to add custom code into the `HelloCli.call()` method with a loop that collects the help texts from the two classes that implement the functions. But not sure how. I have not found any sample code for this popular use case.

My additional question is similar to the first one:
Can I show somehow the full help that is shown together everything from `Case 2` and `Case 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the section on subcommands, [Making Subcommands Required](https://picocli.info/#_required_subcommands).

Essentially, do not implement Callable or Runnable in the top-level command. This makes it mandatory for end users to specify a subcommand. The manual has an example.

About your second question, how to customize the usage help message, please take a look at the picocli-examples module of the picocli GitHub project. A lot of the examples are about custom help.
For example, [this one](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/customhelp/ShowCommandHierarchy.java) shows the full hierarchy of subcommands (and sub-subcommands) in the usage help of the top-level command.

Comment: Can I overwrite the way how the default red message is generated when I execute my app without a parameter? This message: `Missing required options: ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `CommandSpec`, as shown in the [Git example in the picocli-examples repository](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/main/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/git/Git.java). Just add `spec.commandLine().usage(System.err)` to the `call()`/`run()` method of your top-level command.

```java
@Command(name = "cli", subcommands = {ShowUserCommand.class})
public class CLI implements Runnable {

    @Option(names = {"-h", "--help"}, usageHelp = true, description = "Display this usage menu")
    private boolean help;

    @Spec
    CommandSpec spec;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // print the help menu if no subcommand is passed
        spec.commandLine().usage(System.err);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int exitCode = new CommandLine(new CLI()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}

@Command(name = "show-user", description = "Show the current user")
public class ShowUserCommand implements Runnable {
    
    @Option(names = {"-h", "--help"}, usageHelp = true, description = "Display this usage menu")
    private boolean help;
    
    @Option(names = {"-u", "--uppercase"}, description = "Print the username as uppercase")
    private boolean uppercase;

    @Spec
    CommandSpec spec;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
        System.out.println("User: " + (uppercase ? username.toUpperCase() : username));
    }
}
```

Executing the command without any parameters will print the help menu:

[image]

In regards to your followup question, there doesn't seem to be a way to print the full help message (including options for the subcommands), it's required to pass the subcommand with `-h` to see the help for that specific subcommand.